# Random SIGSEGV NSFetchedResultsController crash

Tags: ios, uitableview, segmentation-fault, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Receiving random crash reports related to `NSFetchedResultsController` updates to a `UITableView`, but I'm having a difficult time deciphering the crash log since it's all internal iOS methods.

This occurs at random times after data is fetched from a server in a background queue and the app populates new `NSManagedObjects` in the background into a Core Data Persistent Store.

Does anyone have an understanding of what may be going on here?

```
SIGSEGV

0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x3930b752 lookUpImpOrForward + 46
1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x39303feb _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 35
2   libobjc.A.dylib 0x39303db9 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 25
3   UIKit 0x317b2bbf __66-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]_block_invoke + 451
4   UIKit 0x31778179 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 3717
5   UIKit 0x3189c95b -[UITableViewRowData ensureAllSectionsAreValid] + 167
6   UIKit 0x31873f29 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 217
7   CoreData 0x2ecae7dd -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 4013
8   CoreFoundation 0x2eef4121 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 13
9   CoreFoundation 0x2ee68317 _CFXNotificationPost + 1719
10  Foundation 0x2f84cdcd -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 77
11  CoreData 0x2ecad813 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 79
12  CoreData 0x2ecad7ab -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] + 299
13  CoreData 0x2ecabe13 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2367
14  CoreData 0x2ed159e3 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentProcessSaveRequest:inContext:error:] + 1315
15  CoreData 0x2ed1632f __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 563
16  libdispatch.dylib 0x397f31a7 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 67
17  libdispatch.dylib 0x397ebd67 _dispatch_client_callout + 23
18  libdispatch.dylib 0x397f27c1 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 269
19  CoreFoundation 0x2eefc821 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
20  CoreFoundation 0x2eefb0f5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1301
21  CoreFoundation 0x2ee65ce7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
22  CoreFoundation 0x2ee65acb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
23  GraphicsServices 0x33b86283 GSEventRunModal + 139
24  UIKit 0x31707a41 UIApplicationMain + 1137
25   0x000ba53f main (main.m:16)
```